# How to write this term compactly?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, transformation

How can I write this term in a compact form where $a$ only appears once on the RHS (in particular without cases)?

$T(a) =
  \begin{cases}
    a^2  &,\text{ if $a \leq 0$}\\
    2a^2 &,\text{ if $a > 0$}\\
  \end{cases}$

I have already thought about $T(a) = \max\{\sqrt{2}a,|a|\}^2$ or $T(a) = \frac{3+\text{sgn}(a)}{2}a^2$, but in both cases $a$ appears twice.

Comment: With standard functions, I doubt it is possible.

Comment: $$T(a)=f(a)$$ hopefully there are no restrictions on defining $f$ :p

Comment: @John Joy Good one, that is indeed the only solution I came up with myself. However, it still lacks the elegance I am aiming for (as you might guess) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discussing the problem with a brilliant friend we came up with the following solution:

$T(a) = \left[\Re\left((\sqrt[4]{2}-i)\sqrt{a}\right)\right]^4$

However, I am still up for further suggestions!

Comment: Did you mean $\left[\Re\left((\sqrt[4]2-i)\sqrt a\right)\right]^4$? (Also, the $-$ could be a $+$—doesn't matter.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw Oh man, yeah - typo!

Answer (score -1):

Another class of solutions to this problem is the "trivial substitution class".

**Examples**

$$T(a) = 2\int_0^a x\cdot(\max\{x,0\}+1)dx$$

or even more trivial

$$T(a) = \max\{\sqrt{2}x,|x|\}^2\bigg|_{x=a}$$

Comment: This answer is effectively saying that an expression for $f(a)$, where $a$ appears many times can be represented by $\int_{a_0}^af'(x)\ \mathrm{d}x-f(a_0)$, which is disingenuous since the free variable $x$ is just taking place of $a$. It's like saying that $f(a)=f(b)$, where $b=a$.

Comment: @Jam True, that is why I called it "trivial substitution". However, it is actually an answer to the question and should thus not be downvoted.